# What are the words spoken in the Futurama theme song?

Tags: futurama

In the first few seconds of the original Futurama theme song three indecipherable words are spoken. To me it sounds like `kip, kip pay` which seems nonsensical.

Comment: I’ve always assumed it was “one two, two three” like a count in, but never really listened that closely

Comment: It's clearly a count, as you can hear during the breakdown (at around 1:58) of the "extended" version: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tz8HmN2uvuk

Comment: The theme also contains a hidden *"Futurama!"*  https://www.reddit.com/r/futurama/comments/m5vpgf/the_futurama_theme_song_contains_a_vocoded/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to match fairly well to what i heard in the song.

https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/Christopher-Tyng/Futurama-Series-Theme-TV-Version

The only exceptions being:

```
(1) I will get 24 centry up his Ass -> Imma get 24th century up his ass

(2)Im a fend (i fend gerders)  -> Im a bender (i bend gerders).
```

(2) Source -

They both are audio clips from the pilot of the series "Space Pilot 3000"
Transcript of the episode - https://theinfosphere.org/Transcript:Space_Pilot_3000

In relation to your original question the "kip, kip pay" i think is "one two, two three".